# Instrumental function vs. instrumental line profile?

Tags: optics, terminology, spectroscopy

I am reading into spectroscopy and the terms [instrumental function](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=instrumental+function) and [instrumental line profile](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=instrumental+line+profile) come up regularly. I have reason to believe that they are not equivalent but cannot find any clear definitions of these terms. So what is the difference between them and how can they be defined?

Comment: The instrumental profile or function would be the line shape produced by the spectrometer if it was illuminated by a perfectly monochromatic line. If you fold the real spectrum with this instrument response then you will get the measured spectrum. The finite line width of the instrumental response limits the ability to distinguish lines that are close to each other and the correct deconvolution of a measured spectrum is a non-trivial data analysis problem.

Comment: And to add to @CuriousOne's comment (at least it wasn't clear to me): the instrument function will (likely) not be a constant but will vary with wavelength. This only makes the non-trivial data analysis problem more, well, non-trivial...

Comment: By "fold" @CuriousOne means "convolve".

Comment: @DanielSank: Indeed. Did I fall victim to one of my pet Germanisms, again? :-) Jon Custer: Indeed, indeed. Let's not scare the OP even more than he already should be?

Comment: @CuriousOne Almost. If I notice you start posting "faltung" I'll throw a bucket of cold water at you :-).

Comment: @CuriousOne Would it be possible to give an example?

Comment: Scroll down to the 2nd paragraph et. seq. of [this excerpt from The Great Soviet Encyclopedia](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Spectroscopic+Instruments) for an example of how the instrumental function is a trade-off between the resolving power and the transmission of radiant flux and signal-to-noise ratio an instrument is capable of.  You may find this [general tutorial in spectroscopy](http://www.pondpol.com/appnotes/analytical/HJYTutorial%20in%20Spectroscopy.pdf) helpful, particularly section 1.5, if I understand it rightly.

Comment: @CuriousOne Here is what I have gathered so far, let us say we have a spectrum $f(\lambda)$ then this if we measure this spectrum we would ideally want to get $f(\lambda)$ however, we will get another function $F(\lambda)$ as our measured spectrum where $F(\lambda)=f(\lambda)*g(\lambda)$ where $*$ represents the convolution and $g(\lambda)$ is the instrumental profile.

Comment: Here is a source: "Progress in optics, Volume 3" pg 147 by E. Wolf